# How to manually find residual/regression SS and Standard Error

Tags: excel, vba, statistics

I have been utilizing the **Analysis ToolPak Add-Ins** built in **Regression** tool in order to determine whether or not a stock's historical returns (*Y-Range*) compared that to the VFINX (*X-Range*) are significantly valid as seen below:
[image: Regression Output]

In this case, the **F value is < 4** and **t-stat is < 1.67**, implying that this stock should be skipped over.

I am interested in determining the steps this tool takes provided the given inputs to calculate these statistics in order to manually compute them within VBA.

Here is what I know so far:

```
F = Regression MS / Residual MS
MS = SS / df
Total SS = DEVSQ(Y-Range)
Regression df = 1
Residual df = Count(Y-Range) - 2
Total df = Count(Y-Range) - 1
t-stat = Beta / StandardError
beta = Slope(Y-Range, X-Range)
```

The calculations I am missing are:

```
Regression SS = ??
Residual SS = ??
StandardError = ??
```

I am hoping that there is a relatively easy function/formula that I can utilize to calculate these missing values, as I am not looking to keep the process lean and fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit more digging I found the `LINEST` function that handles this perfectly.

For the F Value:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(Y-Range, X-Range, TRUE, TRUE),4)
```

For the t-stat:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(Y-Range, X-Range, TRUE, TRUE),1) / INDEX(LINEST(Y-Range, X-Range, TRUE, TRUE),2)
```